# Select and Update Tables in mysql in same mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have mysql query :-

```
select id,CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,Min(RunNo) as run,IsDominant,IsActive from RequestInfo
group by CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo 
having concat(CustomerName,Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,count(RunNo)) in
(select concat(CustomerName,Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,Min(Total)) from
(select CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo, count(RunNo) Total from RequestInfo
group by CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo
) b 
group by CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef);
```

which gives output :-

```
   +------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+--------+------+------------+----------+
   | id   | CustomerName | Scenario     | StepNo | InTransit | IsAlef | run  | IsDominant | IsActive |
   +------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+--------+------+------------+----------+
   |    1 | Cleartrip    | SearchFlight | 1      | No        | No     | 1    | NULL       | NULL     |
   |  327 | HotStar      | SearchTv     | 1      | No        | No     | 1    | NULL       | NULL     |
   |  836 | NDTV         | LiveTv       | 1      | No        | No     | 2    | NULL       | NULL     |
   | 1090 | YATRA        | SearchFlight | 1      | No        | No     | 2    | NULL       | NULL     |
   +------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+--------+------+------------+----------+
```

i want to set the last two columns as "Yes" only for the rows which are been shown in the above result.

Comment: you need to update on table or only on select statement?

Comment: can you add the ID column to your table ? That will make it much more easier.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ i want to update table as " YES"

Comment: @atayenel i have edited the question with ID column.

Comment: You're using, and possibly misusing, the nonstandard MySQL extension to GROUP BY. Your query returns *unpredictable* values of `id`. This unpredictability could possibly lead to mistakes if you use those `id` values in the `WHERE` clause of an `UPDATE` query. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @O.Jones what is your suggestion then.

Comment: I hesitate to offer a suggestion because I don't really understand what you're trying to do. I don't want to guess by reading your query, due to the `GROUP BY` problem. Please [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: @O.Jones       the query gives me proper output only thing is that i want to update the "IsDominant" and is "IsActive" columns only for those rows.